# How to make clear icon always appear in Flutter searchbar

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I have a search bar like this in my Flutter project and it's working fine but I'm just wondering how can I keep X icon even though a user click "Enter" on their keyboard or when they click the screen outside of the search bar?.

Currently the X icon is showing only when a user tap on the search bar. Basically I want X Icon to appear as long as there is user text on the search bar.

Search Icon will appear back when ever the search bar is empty.

Any suggestion or help would be really appreciated.
[image]

[image]

```
           Row(  
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                      child: Container(                       
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Expanded(
                              child: Container(
                                margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 6),
                                child: TextFormField(
                                    focusNode: _focusNode,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 16,
                                        color: Colors.black
                                        height: 1,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w100),
                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                        hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.black
                                            fontSize: 16,
                                            height: 1,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w100),
                                        border: InputBorder.none,
                                        hintText: "Search"),
                                    onChanged: (text) {
                                      loadData();
                                    },
                                    controller: search),
                              ),
                            ),
                            focused.value == true
                                ? GestureDetector(
                                    onTap: () {
                                      search.clear();
                                      FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(
                                          new FocusNode()); //remove focus
                                      focused.value = false;
                                      (context as Element).markNeedsBuild();
                                    },
                                    child: SvgPicture.asset(
                                      iconsPath + "close.svg",
                                      color: Colors.black
                                      width: 20,
                                    ),
                                  )
                                : loading.value
                                    ? SpinKitFadingCube(
                                        color: Colors.blue
                                        size: 16.0,
                                      )
                                    : SvgPicture.asset(
                                        iconsPath + "search.svg",
                                        color:  Colors.black
                                        width: 20,
                                      )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
           
                  ),
                ],
              ),
```

Comment: Your current implementation is triggering off of `focused.value`. Instead, add a `TextEditingController` with a listener so you can update state based on what the user has typed.

https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/forms/text-field-changes#interactive-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `TextEditingController` for check icon:

Try:

```
          Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        child: Container(
                          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 6),
                          child: TextFormField(
                              focusNode: _focusNode,
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 16,
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  height: 1,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w100),
                              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                  hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      fontSize: 16,
                                      height: 1,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w100),
                                  border: InputBorder.none,
                                  hintText: "Search"),
                              onChanged: (text) {
                                setState(() {
                                  // loadData();
                                });
                              },
                              controller: search),
                        ),
                      ),
                      search.text.isNotEmpty
                          ? GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () {
                                search.clear();
                                FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(
                                    new FocusNode()); //remove focus
                                // _focusNode.hasFocus = false;
                                (context as Element).markNeedsBuild();
                              },
                              child: Icon(CupertinoIcons.clear),
                            )
                          : Icon(CupertinoIcons.search)
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

Answer (score 1):

In your current implementation, you have used "focused.value" instead try adding texteditingcontroller to Textformfield and check its value length.